# How to change CSS Background image size without changing background position dimension

Tags: css

My project have social icons. Its created by using large icons image and changing background positions. I want to change background image size without change image size. 
Images are used like this.

```
ul.social-profile li.facebook a {background-position: 0px 0px;}
ul.social-profile li.twitter a {background-position: -44px 0px;}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Provide html/css and/or use `background-size: width height;`

Comment: Prefer to make a JSFiddle.